# AAD Connect sync - Why accounts disabled in on-prem AD not disabled in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a client who is using AAD Connect sync 2.1.20 to sync accounts from on-prem AD to Azure AD.

I have recently discovered that some of the disabled accounts in on-prem AD don't have their synced entities disabled in Azure AD, in other words these accounts are still enabled in Azure AD.

I ran the Azure AD Connect Single Object Sync PowerShell script to diagnose the problem. The report generated shows that AAD Connect finds the AD account has the **UserAccountControl** value of **0x202**, which means **"Normal account" (0x200)** + **"Disabled" (0x002)**. However, with the default transformation rule the imported object to the AAD Connector space have "**accountEnabled**" attribute ended up as "**True**", which subsequently resulted in the account in AAD not disabled.

The default transformation rule is this:
**Transformation_Rule**

[image]

The transformation it uses is this:

```
IIF(BitAnd([userAccountControl],2)=0,True,False)
```

With the "userAccountControl" value being **0x202**, this rule should result in "**False**", yet the resulted "**userEnabled**" value was "**True**".

Note that the transformation rule is from a cloned rule.  We cloned the default "In from AD - User Common" rule in order to add an attribute to determine if a user should be hidden from Exchange GAL. The transformations screenshot was taken from the cloned rule.

Here is the default rule we cloned from, it has been disabled:
[image: Default rule: In from AD - User Common]

Here is the rule we created from the clone:
[image: Cloned rule]

Can someone let me know why the transformation rule resulted an on-prem disabled account to an enabled AAD account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have also been stuck on this for quite some time. I found a solution. I deleted the original rule (`precedence 106`) and moved my cloned rule to `precedence 106` and run a delta sync. Now my disabled users are showing in AAD as expected.

Comment: Thanks Simon for sharing it, will try it when I get around to it.